# Converting Columns into Rows in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

i have a table below that looks like the current one below. How can i put the values for date, count2, amount2 from columns into rows just ONCE?

current:

```
date   type count amount type2  date count2 amount2
1/1/20  00    5    13.49  ZZZ  1/1/20    0      5.00
1/1/20  12    6    14.69  ZZZ  1/1/20    0      5.00
1/1/20  11    10   20.66  ZZZ  1/1/20    0      5.00
```

expected

```
date   type count amount
1/1/20  12    6    14.69  
1/1/20  12    6    14.69   
1/1/20  11    10   20.66  
1/1/20  ZZZ   0    5.00
```

Answer (score 2):

what can you do it just splits data flow into two **select** steps.
in the **first** select step use your first three columns.
in the **second** select step use your remaining other columns. and use filter rows to remove redundancy. then use **dummy** step and link to both select steps.